# execveat(2) / fexecve(3) like behavior with Python’s subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, execve

How can I get Python’s *subprocess* module to accept an fd
instead of a path (== *execveat()* with `AT_EMPTY_PATH`)?
Example:

```
subprocess.Popen (["argv0", "argv1"], shell=False,
                  executable=os.open ("/proc/self/exe",
                                      os.O_RDONLY
                                      | os.O_CLOEXEC))
```

With Python 3.6.5 this fails on account of TypeError.

The goal is, of course, avoiding the TOCTTOU between validating
the binary and the call to *execve(2)*.

I’m aware that *os.execve()* can be used with fds too but I’d
prefer not to reimplement the *subprocess* module on top of that.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue23459

Comment: Using `/proc/self/fd/N` would suit most needs.

Comment: @minmaxavg “Using /proc/self/fd/N would suit most needs.” – Please post an answer how to do that with subprocess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPython's [`_posixsubprocess`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c), the internal implementation of [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html) for POSIX, supports neither `fexecve(3)` nor `execveat(2)`. If you can assume `/proc` is mounted, then simply specify `/proc/self/fd/N` (where N is the desired fd) as the executable. This is also what `fexecve(3)` falls back to on older kernels. See Linux manpage `proc(5)` for details on `/proc/self/fd`.

**EDIT** Example:

```
def spawn_exefd(args, fd, bufsize=-1, *args, **kwargs):
    return subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize, "/proc/self/fd/%d" % (fd,), *args, **kwargs)

#import fcntl # py2
import os
fd = os.open("/bin/sh", os.O_RDONLY | os.O_CLOEXEC)
#fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD) | fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC) # py2
spawn_exefd(["sh", "-i"], fd)
```